# Ajax post not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, .post

I'm new in ajax and try to get data from a post request. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){

  $.post("10.0.0.10/info/page.php",
        {
          id: "1234"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("succesData: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        })  
        .fail(function(data,status) {
            alert("failData: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
    }); 
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input id="id" type="text">
<button>Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I just try page.php page with html form and get this json:

> [{"cabin_id":"1234","city":"","type":"","year":"2009"}]

So 10.0.0.10/info/page.php working fine but my ajax code can't get data. I only get .fail alert box and it says:

[image: alert box]

What is wrong on my ajax code?

EDIT:

I see this error now:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/KUVALYA/Desktop/post. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Comment: check your console window - you may have some errors there?

Comment: "I only get .fail alert box" — And what does it say?

Comment: another thing to try - console.log(data);

you'll be able to inspect the object's data better than an alert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking from the IP address, i think its external domain.

Your ajax will never work unless you enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing on the target IP

Please enable CORS by setting appropriate headers as mentioned in the following link and then use ajax on the target.

More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

---

If possible, you can use JSON padding ([JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)) but that too requires customizing the response at the server side

Hope it helps!

Comment: I try it with PHP **file_get_contents()** and i can read data. Isnt that means Cross Origin Resource Sharing enabled on the target IP?

Comment: CORS only affects ajax calls, this has no effect on PHP

Comment: Thx Hermant. I think you are right, my problem is CORS. I can't use JSONP because cant change anytihng in server side. So i change my route and programing a java program :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the scheme (e.g. `https://`) or start the URL with `//` (indicating that it is relative to the current scheme) then the first part will be treated as a directory, not a hostname.

You are requesting something like: `http://example.com/foo/10.0.0.10/info/page.php`.

Correct your URL.

Comment: Then either that's the wrong URL in some different way or you have some other problem. Look at your browser's developer tools. What do they tell you? Are there errors in the console? Does you see the request and response you expect in the Net tab?

Comment: Hİ. sorry for late response. I see an error now on chrome: **XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/KUVALYA/Desktop/post. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.**

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Cross%20origin%20requests%20are%20only%20supported%20for%20protocol%20schemes:%20http,%20data,%20chrome,%20chrome-extension,%20https,%20chrome-extension-resource